# Most general form of Poincaré duality in étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory, etale-cohomology, six-operations

I am interested in Poincaré duality from the point of view of Grothendieck's 6-functor formalism. I am predominantly interested in the proof that Poincaré duality holds in étale cohomology from this perspective. Where is there an account of the most generic situation in which Poincaré duality of an étale cohomology arises?

Comment: Can you clarify (for us non english-speaking natives), what you mean by "the most generic situation" ?

Comment: @A.B. As a rule of thumb, if two mathematicians choose two categories in different rooms and you can name an essentially surjective functor from one setup $A$ to the other $B$, then $A$ is more generic. The same principle works for $2$-categorical logic, which is the foundations on my computer right now. We might like to speak of the most generic setup when we want to isolate what worked about an idea. I've heard that called sifting in some places.

Comment: @A.B. I would assume it means a setup that is as general as possible, or, equivalently, with the fewest restrictions/assumptions. Not in a technical sense of 'generic', as happens in algebraic geometry, for instance.

Comment: As I understand it, Poincaré duality in étale cohomology comes down to the existence of a suitable trace morphism $Tr_f: Rf_{!}f^{\ast}L(d)[2d]\to L$ for a smooth morphism $f:X\to Y$ pure of relative dimension $d$ and a torsion complex $L$ on $Y$. The trace morphism is constructed, by devissage, from the case of a smooth irreducible projective curve $X$ over an algebraically closed field, where it is taken to be the degree map $\deg: Pic(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$ modulo $n$.

Comment: An easy to navigate reference for this is [Etale cohomology theory, 8.2, 8.3 and 8.5] by Lei Fu.

Comment: [Relevant paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.02875)

Comment: If you really want the most general statement, look at Theorem 0.1.4 here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5948.pdf).

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions.